# PHP If loop for ACF with search for text value

Tags: php, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I created the following if loop with php (I'm a php beginner), with which I can search for a specific search term in the text in an ACF textfield and output a text depending on the result:

This is my code for finding one keyword only and it works fine:

```
$text = get_field('my_acf_field');
$keyword = "text";

$result = strpos($text, $keyword);

if($result === false) {
   echo "Text not found";
} else {
   echo "Text found";
}
```

This works perfectly. Now I would like to extend the code to have several search words output differently. So something along the lines of:

```
$text = get_field('my_acf_field');
$keyword1 = "text";
$keyword2 = "text 2";
$keyword3 = "text 3";

$result = strpos($text, $keyword1, $keyword2, $keyword3);

if($result === $keyword1) {
   echo "Lorem Ipsum 1";
} elseif($result === $keyword2) {
   echo "Lorem Ipsum 2";
} elseif($result === $keyword3) {
   echo "Lorem Ipsum 3";
} else {
   echo "Text not found";
}
```

However, that doesn't work and I can't find my mistake.

Thank you for your help

Mags

Comment: [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) takes three parameters (at most), you pass four. Also, [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the position of the found text, you are comparing the result to strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foundKeywords = [];
foreach ([$keyword1, $keyword2, $keyword3] as $keyword) {
  if (strpos($text, $keyword) !== false) {
    echo 'Found keyword: ' . $keyword;
    $foundKeywords[] = $keyword;
  }
}
if (empty($foundKeywords)) {
  echo 'No keywords found';
}
```

Comment: The code works fine and the result is e.g. "Found keyword: text" Now I want to use different CSS for different results. E.g. if found Keyword is "text" the color is green and if found Keyword is "text 2" the color is red. How to modify the code?

Comment: `echo '<span class="my_special_keyword">Found keyword: ' . $keyword . '</span>';` Then in your stylesheet `.my_special_keyword { color: green; }`